# Venmo payment extension for Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, payment

Is anybody knows payment extension for Magento 1 which supports Venmo?

Answer (score 0):

Yup, it's commonly supports Magento-1.9.x, If you do face any issues please check your logs or check for any interruption from other modules.

Comment: If still face the issue, please share me the details of the issue. I'll try to solve it asap.